# Subset of regression models fit to bootstrap samples failed to converge - how to identify them in R lme4?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, lme4, convergence

I've fitted the same regression model to a thousand bootstrap samples using the `lmer` package in `R`. The only output I saved were the inferential statistics for fixed and random effects. I did not save any output related to the performance to the machine learning algorithm used to fit the models, namely simple maximum likelihood estimation (REML=FALSE).

After running all the simulations, I got about two dozen messages of this kind:

```
25: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ... :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 4.49732 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
26: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ... :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

Since I only get the error messages at the very end, just looking at these error messages I can't identify which of bootstrap sample model they are referring to. So I have two questions:

1. Is there some way to identify these non-converged models post-hoc?
2. If not and if I need to re-run the simulations, which information do I need to record so that I can easily identify non-converged models after the simulations finish running?

Comment: If you decide to rerun them you could use tryCatch with a warning handler.

Comment: @Roland how would that look like in code?

Comment: you could also keep optimiser info ie `mod@optinfo` (also if running again!)